# How do I scroll down to the end of web page using webdriver js and Node js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"))
```

I have tried the above code but it returns window is not defined. 
Data keeps on loading as I scroll down the page until the search data ends.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a very large number instead of the `scrollHeight` attribute.

Something like this

```
  browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);');
```

Comment: browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);'); is scrolling only once and giving me the value. How to make the webpage to wait till it scrolls to (0,10000)?

Comment: What do you mean by `giving me the value.`?

Comment: Basically I am taking the row count, but what is happening the search result shows somewhere around 100 matching results found. When I am capturing the number of rows, it returns me the 25 rows and after using browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);'); it was returing 50 rows. Even If I increased the value of Y to 15000, it was still returning me 50 rows. Search table is a dynamic table which returns different number of rows depending on the input so I wanted to reach to the bottom of the page each time.